# SSH on FreeBSD 8.1 sshd is not running

Tags: ssh, unix, telnet

After reading many pages of documentation and articles on [how to telnet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72116/freebsd-telnet-does-not-take-root-login) or SSH into FreeBSD as root, none have given me a solution that actually works. I am looking for a how-to-remote-into this FreeBSD in less than 10 easy steps.

Current state

- I am running Windows7 on host machine, subnet `192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0`
- can ping the FreeBSD 8.1 host (running on WMWare) at `192.168.1.145`.
- edited `/etc/inetd.conf`, `/etc/rc.conf`. sshd_enable="YES"
- any attempt to telnet via PutTy to `192.168.1.145` return "connection refused"
- `/etc/rc.d/sshd status` returns **`sshd is not runnin0`**. what needs to be done to run it?

At the moment I'll take whichever method is easier secure or not.  No [RTFM](http://meta.serverfault.com/search?q=rtfm) answers please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Undo whatever you did to `inetd.conf`.
2. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, add `PermitRootLogin yes`
3. run `/etc/rc.d/sshd start`

Telnet doesn't work on ssh. You have to connect via ssh in PuTTY.

If you have a firewall up, you'll need to punch a hole.

Security Note: #2 is a **really** terrible idea. You should either:

- add your user to the wheel group so they can `su` to root (`pw groupmod -n wheel -m your-user`)
- install sudo (easiest is `pkg_add -r sudo`).

Comment: I checked and should have added that `PermitRootLogin yes` of  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` was already `yes`. Other maybe relevant and  existing settings are `#PermitUserEnvironment no`, `#UsePAM yes`, `#PermitTunnel no`. `#` means commented out.

Comment: Also to undo `inetd.conf` leaves both `ssh` and `telnet` lines commented with `#` --is that what we want? `#login` remains unchanged and disabled although it looks like it would be something to enable.

Comment: Alright after going back to VMWare snapshot before changing `inetd.conf`, with everything commented out (satisfying 1),  `yes` (2), and `/etc/rc.conf sshd_enabale="YES"`, and then (3), I have `sshd` now running.

Comment: Didn't explicitly set any firewall configurations besides enabling Windows firewall. At last I have connected via PuTTY. Have not yet implemented security note, but this will work for now in this lab environment.

Comment: `inetd` is an old server server; it's useful for somethings like tftp and the ancient time protocols (not NTP), but definitely not ssh. Telnet is a terrible idea all around, it's best to just leave that rotting corpse in the ground if you have any option. Glad to head you've got sshd running. If you do implement a firewall, use `pf` or `ipfw` (preferably the former if you're unfamiliar with either).

Comment: Also, all of the commented out lines in `sshd_config` are the default values. They're in there so you know what sshd is going to do, and if you have to override them to get a particular behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Enable SSH

```
vi /etc/rc.conf
sshd_enable="YES"
```

Start the SSH service

```
/etc/rc.d/sshd start
```

Chech the status

```
/etc/rc.d/sshd onestatus
```